# Existing Android fragments in React Native

Tags: android, android-fragments, react-native

I need to implement HereMaps in android using React Native. 
*HERE Android SDK* provides me MapFragment with a set o features. While React Native is not supporting fragments, is there any way to make Heremaps(with all features) work on android?

Comment: Please check out this answer, hope it will be helpful for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566027/load-fragment-in-a-react-native-app/48573889#48573889