# Load fragment in a React Native app

Tags: android, android-fragments, react-native

I'm developing a bridge between an Android library of mine and ReactNative, to be able to use my library also on hybrid apps.

I first created a basic app with `react-native init` which has the default Android and iOS folders

Then I imported my library with `gradle` and created the files extending `ReactContextBaseJavaModule` and `ReactPackage` to make sure the `App.js` could see and call methods from my library, but now I have a problem.

One of these methods I call from React Native to my Android library gives back a `Fragment` I need to display and I am not sure how to do it.

So far I was able to write java code in the `MainActivity.java` present in the React Native project under the `android` folder to handle it in such a way

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   fragment = MyLibrary.getFragmentMethod();
   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragment, TAG).commit();
}
```

What I wanted to do instead is more like:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout_id, fragment, TAG).commit();
```

But I have no clue how to define which layout my React Native app would use

p.s. I tried to add the line `setContentView(R.layout.main)` in the `onCreate` method but that mede it so that the `App.js` was not visible anymore (probably because was overwriting the ReactNative "layout"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your own container to the existing layout. For example:

```
window.decorView.findViewById<ViewGroup>(android.R.id.content)
            .addView(
                    FrameLayout(this).apply {
                        id = R.id.fragment_container
                        layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                        )
                    }
            )
```

Now you can add your fragment to this container. 
Also this library might be helpful - https://github.com/hudl/react-native-android-fragment

Comment: Thank you very much, in the end it's possible also to simply add the fragment into `android.R.id.content`
I was just not sure whether this could/should have done via javascript or in the `MainActivity`

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works in our react native project. we need a container id to add fragment and android.R.id.content worked like a charm